# Core Data custom section header / index

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data

i want to have complete names in the section headers generated by Core Data.
Currently its only showing the First letter / number (it displays float numbers as int), but i want to display it as a float number (7.12 for example).

I want to have more than one charakter in the Index / header of a section.

Therefore I thought I need to overwrite the NSFetchedResultsController's method :

```
- (NSString *)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller sectionIndexTitleForSectionName:(NSString *)sectionName
```

So, I created a subclass of NSFetchedResultsController and included it in my controller which fetches the data. But the method seems not to be overwritten..

Am I doing something false at overwriting this method?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement that method on the delegate of the `NSFetchedResultsController`, not in a subclass.